# Intersection of principal neighborhoods of a point in a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $U,V$ be two affine open subsets. I want to show that for every $x \in U \cap V$ there exists a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U \cap V$ which is principal both in $U$ and $V$.

My idea was to say that there exists a principal neighborhood of $x$ in $U$ which I will write $U_x$ and one in $V$ which I will write $V_x$. What I am trying to do is to show that $U_x \cap V_x$ is principal in $U$ and $V$. I've been unsuccesfull which might or might not be an indication that this is not the way to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U \cap V$ is covered by basic-open subsets $C$ of $U$, and each of them is covered by basic-open subsets $B$ of $V$. Since $C \to V$ is a morphism of affine schemes, it pulls back basic-open subsets of $V$ to basic-open subsets of $C$. It follows that $B$ is also basic-open in $C$. Since $C$ is basic-open in $U$, it follows that $B$ is basic-open in $U$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Is it obvious that is $B$ is basic in $C$ and $C$ basic in $U$ then $B$ is basic in $U$ ?

Comment: Try to think about it. Use $(A_f)_{\dfrac{g}{f^k}}=A_{fg}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, is see. Thanks again !